# Can you merge your data without creating separate dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

My data frame is something like the follows:

```
sex year country value
F 2010 AU 350
F 2011 GE 258
M 2010 AU 250
F 2012 GE 928
```

In order to create another data frame that is merged by year and country, with sex and value being what you want to compare, you must first create separate data frames, like:

```
f <- subset(df, sex=="F")
m <- subset(df, sex=="M")
df_new <- merge(f, m, by=c("country", "year"), suffixes=c("_f", "_m"))
```

In this way, you can obtain a new data frame with year, and country being matched and just the value being different.

However, I don't like to bother to create separate data frames in order to merge. Is it possible to just write a code in one-line to achieve the data frame?

Comment: What would happen in the case of `F 2011 GE`?

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli Oops. I should check it out... thanks

Comment: That's just reshaping from long to wide: `library(tidyr); df %>% spread(sex, value) %>% na.omit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `dput(dft)` as :

```
structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
year = c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2012), 
country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("AU", "GE"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(350, 258, 250, 928)), .Names = c("sex", "year", "country", "value"),row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

you can use `tidyverse` and do:

```
dft %>% spread(sex,value)
```

which gives:

```
#  year country   F   M
#1 2010      AU 350 250
#2 2011      GE 258  NA
#3 2012      GE 928  NA
```

Comment: Sorry for being late; I was learning about dplyr and tidyr. This is definitely what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `split` and then with `Reduce/merge` can get the expected output

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c("country", "year"),
           suffixes = c("_f", "_m")), split(df, df$sex))
#    country year sex_f value_f sex_m value_m
#1      AU 2010     F     350     M     250
```

NOTE: This should also work when there are 'n' number of `unique` elements in the `split` `by` column (without the `suffixes` or its modification)

---

A reshaping option with `data.table` is

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(dcast(setDT(df), country + year ~ rowid(country, year), 
                                        value.var = c("sex", "value")))
#   country year sex_1 sex_2 value_1 value_2
#1:      AU 2010     F     M     350     250
```